# Dispatcher in WPF ViewModel Class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using a dispatcher in one of my WPF code behind but now moving all code behind to MVVM pattern with below code:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CallEmployee()));
Thread.Sleep(100000);
```

but the same is not available from a ViewModel Class file. I tried

```
System.Windows.Threading.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => CallEmployee()));
Thread.Sleep(100000);
```

but its not calling `CallEmployee` method.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(100000);` ????  Something very wrong is going on here.

Answer (score 4):

If your ViewModel is located in an assembly that references `WindowsBase.dll` and `PresentationFramework.dll`, then you can do:

`System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...);`

Otherwise, you need to abstract the dispatcher, probably by using some interfaces and Factory pattern or IoC or whatever.